# Should I listen to my mother who doesn't let me do wudu because I can get sick?

Tags: wudu, parents

I'm a teenager (less then 15) and my mom doesn't let me wudu when its Fajr and sometimes other praying times in the winter. Her reason behind this is because I can get sick (as in very sick; I think she afraid that I can get asthma since I have been brought in for that many times). She said that when my immune system gets stronger she'll allow me to do do wudu.

My question is: should I listen to her?

Parents are ranked very high and we should do our best to listen to them.  Especially if it's our mother.

Or do it secretly? I told her about this and she even said she's willing to take the sin.

Comment: Is Wudu at Fajr time harmfull for you in any way or is your mother being protective? If it is harmful then you should ask for what other alternatives are available to you because of your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can take the sin on behalf of others. You can use hot water. If you are really afraid that you are going to get a severe sickness from the Wuduu, then you can do Tayammum.  I advice you to ask a doctor about your condition, a Muslim doctor preferably ..

see:
 https://islamqa.info/en/105356

Comment: I tried talking about this again..but she straight out ignored me and said it still isn't my time.  I'm 13 btw. Almost 14.

Comment: @plzdon'tjudgeme if you reached puberty you are considered as mature (mukallaf) and prayer is ordered for you and you should do your best to follow this order. Else if you are not mukallaf yet, you should obey your parents however finding a middleway would be better. BTW I suffered from asthma myself cold water or whatever you have described has no influence on this illness.

Comment: I'm 13 and have asthma. I have no problem in doing wudhu. It wouldn't affect your body. The only water that would affect me is cold chlorinated water, like in swimming pools but swimmingl pool water is not cold so the best example is if you go on a waterslide. I went on one recently and got a little cough.

Comment: Thanks..but if my mom does get too forceful and say that I can't. What should I say in my prayer that I can repent to Allah. This argument happens toward Fajr prayer.